# How to toggle visibility of a div based on div content

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I've been poking around in similar questions but nothing has quite matched what I'm trying to do.

Basically, I'm working on a simple chrome extension for fun / to teach myself how scripts interact with chrome. I got a simple script working that will show/hide a given div:

```
function showHide() {
    var e = document.getElementsByClassName("Line");

    for ( var i=0, len=e.length; i<len; ++i ){

        if(e[i].style.display == 'block')
            e[i].style.display = 'none';
        else
            e[i].style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

As you'd expect, this hides every instance of "Line" on the page. The next step is to try to hide only divs that contain a certain string. I've been playing around with 'innerHTML.indexOf("Line")' but so far nothing has worked. Most often I'm getting this error: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined**

Intuitively, I'm trying to make something along the lines of:

```
if (e.innerHTML.indexOf("foo") != -1) { showHide(e); }
```

But I'm not sure how to integrate that conditional with the showHide() function I have working. I think I'm handling the 'if' statements sloppily, but since I'm pretty rusty with javascript, I'm mostly working by trial and error.

Just posting here in hope I can get some tips/direction.

Comment: Try using an index. Instead of `e.innerHTML.indexOf("foo")` use `e[i].innerHTML.indexOf("foo")` in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can try iterating through the child nodes and checking their Inner Html. Check out the snippet.

Cheers!

```js
var showHide = function(e) {
  e.style.display = (e.style.display === 'block') ? 'none' : 'block'
}

function toggle() {
  doStuff();
}

function eContainsNodeValue(element, foo){
  
  var childs = element.childNodes;
  for (j = 0; j<childs.length; j++){
    if (childs[j].innerHTML === foo)
      return true;
  }
  return false;
}

function doStuff() {
  var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("Line");
  for (i = 0; i< elements.length; i++){
    if (eContainsNodeValue(elements[i], 'foo'))
      showHide(elements[i]);
  }
}
```

```css
#MyDiv {
  background-color: #6699ff;
}
.Line {
  display: block;
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #6699ff;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<body id="MyDiv">
  <div class="Line" style="display: block">
    <h4>I'm a line 1!</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="Line" style="display: block">
    <h4>I'm a line 2!</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="Line" style="display: block">
    <h4>I'm a line 3!</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="Line" style="display: block">
    <h4>I'm a line 4!</h4>
    <p>foo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Line" style="display: block">
    <h4>I'm a line 5!</h4>
    <p>bar</p>
  </div>
  <div class="Line" style="display: block">
    <h4>I'm a line 6!</h4>
  </div>
  <button onclick="toggle()">Toggle foo bar</button>
</body>
```